# How to run an export command within the docker entrypoint?

Tags: python, docker, conda, gunicorn, datadog

I'm trying to integrate Datadog APM tracing and log collection to a python application running on Docker.
Within the Dockerfile, I need to activate the conda virtual env and export an env DD_AGENT_HOST.

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

WORKDIR /app

COPY src ./src
COPY application.yaml .
COPY wsgi.py .
COPY gunicorn.conf.py .
COPY logging.ini .

RUN conda env create -f application.yaml

SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "dd_venv", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "dd_venv", "ddtrace-run", "gunicorn", "-c", "gunicorn.conf.py", "wsgi:app", "--preload"]
```

I'm able to run the application using the above Dockerfile. However, it is required to export the env DD_AGENT_HOST for the application to connect with Datadog and the value of DD_AGENT_HOST has to be retrieved via an HTTP request.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "dd_venv", "export DD_AGENT_HOST=$(wget <ip_ddress>)", "ddtrace-run", "gunicorn", "-c", "gunicorn.conf.py", "wsgi:app", "--preload"]
```

I tried adding the export command to the ENTRYPOINT as above, which causes Docker run to fail with the error
"export DD_AGENT_HOST=: command not found:.

What is the correct way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Have you tried just `"DD_AGENT_HOST=$(wget <ip_address>)"`, without the export?

Comment: @merv thanks for trying to help. I was able to solve it in a different way. Please refer my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the shell form of CMD and combining the command to export the environment variable and the command to start the application.

```
CMD export DD_AGENT_HOST=$(wget <ip_address>); ddtrace-run gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py wsgi:app --preload
```

I had to add the `--no-capture-output` with SHELL to enable logs being written to `sdout` and `stderr`.

```
SHELL ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "dd_venv", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running it through an activated Conda environment, it should be possible to add an activation script to the environment that includes the command. For example, a file like:

**/path/to/envs/dd_venv/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/sh

export DD_AGENT_HOST=$(wget <ip_address>)
```

See [the documentation on *Saving Environment Variables*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/master/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables).

Note that for static environment variables (e.g., strings you know *a priori*), these could be directly integrated into your **application.yaml** file. See [the documentation on *Setting Environment Variables*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/master/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables).

Comment: I tried this out.  Although the DD_AGENT_HOST is initialized from the script, it is not accessible to the application it seems. I wonder whether this has anything to do with having another "conda run" in the ENTRYPOINT.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put a lot into that single `ENTRYPOINT` line; I'd break it up a little bit.

First of all, the actual command you're trying to run is at the very end of that line, and I'd make that command be the Dockerfile `CMD`:

```sh
CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "gunicorn.conf.py", "wsgi:app", "--preload"]
```

Having an actual `CMD` is valuable here mostly because it's easy to replace it.  If you want to double-check whether the application is actually running inside the Conda environment, or the environment is being set properly, you can `docker run --rm ... sh -c 'echo $DD_AGENT_HOST'` and that command will replace `CMD`, but still run via the `ENTRYPOINT`.

What goes in `ENTRYPOINT`?  You want to do two things now, and you can write them in a script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# 1. Set a dynamic environment variable
export DD_AGENT_HOST=$(wget <ip_ddress>)

# 2. Run whatever the command is, in the Conda environment,
# with the tracing wrapper.
exec conda run \
  --no-capture-output \
  -n dd_venv \
  ddtrace-run \
  "$@"
```

That script can then be the image's `ENTRYPOINT`.

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh .           # should be executable on the host already
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array syntax
```

In general, you can put anything in that script, and so long as the script ends with `exec "$@"` or some variant on it, everything in the script runs in order before it hands control over to the `CMD`.